# Multiple reusable SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

(*Note I am getting an error submitting to stackoverflow if i use "select", so have misspelled my queries.* [Now Fixed])

Sorry this is a newbie question. I have one very long SQL query that is getting harder to manage. In fact there are some sub-queries that are being used multiple times. What is the best way to break up the query? I would prefer to keep it in the database, rather than take it out into the calling program. It goes something like this.

```
Select A, B, C
from (select D from Table_1 where ...)
Union Select E, F
from Table_2
  Inner Join (Select D, E, from Table_1 where...)..
```

So what I would like to do is

```
Result1 = select D,E from Table_1 where....

Result2 = Select A,B,C from Result_1 Union Select E,F from Table_2 Inner Join Result_1 ...
```

What is the best way to do this? I can't use Views because I don't have privileges. How can I use the results from the first query in the second query? Can cursors be used in this case?

Comment: This is a task for Common Table Expressions aka CTEs, check the WITH syntax.

Comment: With WITH, I have to re-write the query for Result_1 multiple times in my loooong sql query

Comment: @user2689782 - using WITH means you *don't* have to re-write the query; maybe you're using it wrong?

Comment: If it's the same query you have to write it exactly one time using a CTE

Comment: Oh, oh...sorry I see what you mean about WITH . I know select D,E from.. don't look exactly the same, but it is the same logic essentially. But I think that WITH might do the trick...thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Using a CTE you can access the same subquery multiple times (this is the main difference to Derived Tables):

```
with CTE as
 (Select D, E, from Table_1 where...)
Select A, B, C
from CTE
Union 
Select E, F
from Table_2
  Inner Join CTE ..
```

Comment: OK, new problem. I am trying to run this on Excel...which doesn't support 'with'. Any idea how to do it without the with statement please?

Comment: @user2689782: Excel doesn't know SQL, if you connect to Oracle you can submit any valid Oracle syntax?

Comment: You can make an odbc connection - general select, join etc statements seem to be working. But the concept of creating a temporary table seems to be failing...it works in my SQL developer, but not when invoked from Excel. I don't know if there is some  security setting or the like that is preventing this. Driving me totally nuts...but thanks so much for your help.